# Measure of an increasing union

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following proposition.

**Proposition:** Suppose $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{S}, \mu)$ is a measurable space, and $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset \cdots$ is an increasing sequence of elements of $\mathcal{S}$. Then
$$\mu \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(E_k).$$

I managed to prove the proposition for the case where $\mu(E_k) < \infty$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For the case where $\mu(E_k) = \infty$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, it is easy to show that $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(E_k) = \infty$; however, I could not show that the left side is equal to $\infty$. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E_k \subset \cup_k E_k $, so $\mu(E_k)\le \mu(\cup_k E_k)$. If the limit of measure goes to $\infty$, then the mesure of the union as something bigger must go to $\infty$ as well.

Comment: That was trivial. How did I miss that :) Thanks for the answer.